# Store output from command execution to array

Tags: c, unix, output

I have an array `char buffer[300]` in which I would like to store the output from executing `system("ls")`. How do I do this? More specifically I want it to be similar to my pesudocode:

```
int main(void) {
    char buffer[300];
    //store output to buffer
    system("ls");

    //after storing output from system("ls") print buffer to terminal
    //printf(buffer);
}
```

Comment: see [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with `system()`.  You can do it with [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)
if your system supports it.

**An example similar to your pseudocode** (not incredibly efficient) **:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void runCommand(char* cmd, char* buffer, int size);

int main() {
    char buffer[300];
    runCommand("ls", buffer, 300);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}

void runCommand(char* cmd, char* buffer, int size) {
    int c, i=0;
    FILE* stream = popen(cmd, "r");
    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && i < size-1)
        buffer[i++] = c;
    buffer[i] = 0; // null terminate string
    pclose(stream);
}
```

**Simpler example - Printing command output line-by-line:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char buffer[300];
    FILE* stream = popen("ls", "r");
    while (fgets(buffer, 300, stream) != NULL)
        printf("%s", buffer);
    pclose(stream);
}
```